# Image is not showing in React app using img tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

My image is not showing in React app. I am trying to fetch the path from JSON and pass the path using props in `<img>` tag.

Example JSON object with the product data:

```
let data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Striped Slim Fit Shirt",
    image: "./Assets/m1.jpg",
    price: 1000,
    category: "Men",
    size: "XL",
    inStock: true,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Full Sleeves Slim Fit Shirt",
    image: "./Assets/m2.jpg",
    price: 2000,
    category: "Men",
    size: "L",
    inStock: true,
  },
];

export default data;
```

My parent component from which I am passing props.

```
import { Fragment } from "react";
import data from "../../DUMMY_DATA";
import ItemList from "./ItemList";

const HomePage = () => {
 
  const availableItems = data.map((products) => (
    <ItemList
      key={products.id}
      images={products.image}
      name={products.name}
      price={products.price}
      category={products.category}
      size={products.size}
    />
  ));

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div>{availableItems}</div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

My child component. Here, console logging shows the correct path, but the `<img>` tag is not rendering it.

```
import { Fragment } from "react";

const ItemList = (props) => {
  const { id, images, name, price, category, size, inStock } = props;
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="container text-center">
        <div className="row row-cols-4" key={id}>
          <div className="col">
            <img src={images} />
          </div>
          <div className="col">{name}</div>
          <div className="col">{size}</div>
          <div className="col">{price}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default ItemList;
```

Comment: Can you check the network tab in Developer Tools does it show any errors? I think you have an issue with the relative/absolute path of an image.

Comment: I checked the network tab and there it shows type is text. Image type is not showing.

Comment: Try doing       <img src={require(images)} />

Comment: not working mate.